# How to find an object by his type and name attributes in controller#create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, findby

Actually I'm testting the [plutus gem](https://github.com/mbulat/plutus) for double entry accounting.I've accounts and transactions.When You want to record an transaction there's to steps:

1-create the 2 accounts that will receive the transaction amount(eg. Cash(debit) & Withdraw(credit).

2-You create a transaction and pass his amount to the debit_account and credit_account, you've created in step number 1.You do it by finding the type of account, and then it's name(see transactions_controller.rb)

**models/account.rb**

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

    set_inheritance_column do
        "type" + "_id"
    end

    validates_presence_of :name, :type
    validates_presence_of :name

    has_many :credit_transactions,  :class_name => "Transaction", :foreign_key => "credit_account_id"
    has_many :debit_transactions,  :class_name => "Transaction", :foreign_key => "debit_account_id"
      has_many :transactions
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :transactions 
end
```

**models/transaction.rb**

```
class Transaction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commercial_document, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :credit_account, :class_name => "Account"
  belongs_to :debit_account, :class_name => "Account"
  belongs_to :account


  validates_presence_of :credit_account, :debit_account, :amount, :description
  validates_associated :credit_account, :debit_account
end
```

**controller/transactions_controller.rb**

```
  def new 

      @transaction = Transaction.new

      respond_to do |format|
          format.html #new.html.erb
          format.json { render :json => @transaction }
        end
    end 

        def create
        @transaction = Transaction.new(params[:transaction])
        @transaction.credit_account = Account.where(:type => params[:type]).where(:name => params[:name]) 
        @transaction.debit_account =  Account.where(:type => params[:type]).where(:name => params[:name])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @transaction.save
            format.html { redirect_to @transaction, :notice => 'Transaction was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :json => @transaction, :status => :created, :location => @transaction }
          else
            format.html { render :action => "new" }
            format.json { render :json => @transaction.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

**transaction/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for @transaction do |f| %>

  <%= f.input :description %>
  <%= f.input :debit_account %>
  <%= f.input :credit_account %>
  <%= f.input :amount %>

  <%= f.button :submit %>   

<% end %>
```

when I submit a transaction I get the following error message

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in TransactionsController#create
Account(#2160906760) expected, got String(#2151988680)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please replace the following code:

```
@transaction.credit_account = Account.where(:type => params[:type]).where(:name => params[:name]) 
@transaction.debit_account =  Account.where(:type => params[:type]).where(:name => params[:name])
```

with

```
@transaction.credit_account = Account.find(:all, :conditions => [:type => params[:type], :name => params[:name]])  
@transaction.debit_account =  Account.find(:all, :conditions => [:type => params[:type], :name => params[:name]])
```

*I hope this helps.*

Comment: I've tried your solution but I get the following message error `undefined method '%' for {:name=>nil}:Hash`. Do you know that's wrong here?

Comment: Can you please check the value of `params[:name]` ? It may nil due to which you are facing this problem...

Comment: Indeed `:name` is nil, How can i set it do not  be nil?

Comment: Actually I am not getting what you want to do in these lines of code...
params[:name] is nil because you are not getting any value for :name from your transactions/_form.html ..

check your params, it would not contain any attribute with name `:name` 

when you are not getting any value for :name then how can you use it!!

Comment: Hoo sorry RAJ I didn't give you a feedback I was a little busy on school these days. Matter fact what I want to do is : 1)create a transaction 2)pass the transaction two accounts :name(:name is an attribute of account not transaction) 3) pass the value of transaction's :amount to each corresponding account(that i find by name). Am I enough clear?If I do not please tell to precise my point.

Comment: Ok.. but from your present code you can't do this bro... As you are not getting any value for :name, params[:name] will return nil... and for solving this problem firstly you have to pass some value for :name and :type in your controller/transactions_controller.rb...

Comment: Can I know what value will you enter in :debit_account and :credit_account ? Is it name of debit account and credit account?   And what should be the :type ?  Is it debit_account or credit_account ?

Comment: Yes indeed I want to pass a name of debitaccount and credit account in :credit_account & :debit_account.

Comment: `@transaction.credit_account = Account.where(:type => 'credit_account').where(:name => params[:credit_account]) 
@transaction.debit_account = Account.where(:type => 'debit_account').where(:name => params[:debit_account])`

Use this, as you have name in :debit_account and :credit_account... Also the type will be 'debit_account' or 'credit_account'

Comment: It still doesn't work.Thank you for tenacity.But I think I must quit using this gem It's very painful to implement.I'm going to create my own solution